# Rotating a sine curve

Tags: javascript, math, curve

I'm drawing out sine curves using the following formula,

```
this.x += this.speed
this.y = this.amp * Math.sin( this.x * this.cycles ) + this.center
```

I'm dotting out points by drawing tiny circles every frame. What this achieves is a nice looking sine curve that draws from left to right. But if I want to rotate this curve so that it draws in a random 360 degree, how should I modify the code? Aka, sometimes I want the curve to be the same drawing from left to right, other times I want it drawing at a 45 degree downwards, sometimes, backwards, etc...

Comment: Do an affine rotational transformation on each point: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69806.html

Answer (score 4):

One option is to calculate the point in Cartesian coordinates, convert to polar, add your angle offset, and convert back to Cartesian again.

```
this.x += this.speed
this.y = this.amp * Math.sin( this.x * this.cycles ) + this.center

this.r = Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
this.a = Math.atan2(this.y, this.x);

this.a += rotation_angle;

this.x = this.r * Math.cos(this.a);
this.y = this.r * Math.sin(this.a);
```

This increases the number of Math library calls from one to five, so I would expect it to be about one fifth as fast as your original calculation. This may or may not be acceptable. We can actually do a little better using the trigonometric identities `sin(a+b) = sin(a)cos(b) + cos(a)sin(b)` and `cos(a+b) = cos(a)cos(b) - sin(a)sin(b)` identities.

For the rotated X-coordinate:

```
  this.r * cos(this.a)
= this.r * cos(atan2(this.y, this.x) + rotation)
= this.r * (cos(atan2(this.y, this.x))cos(rotation) - sin(atan2(this.y, this.x))sin(rotation))
= this.r * ((this.x / this.r)cos(rotation) - (this.y / this.r)sin(rotation))
= this.x * cos(rotation) - this.y * sin(rotation)
```

For the rotated Y-coordinate:

```
  this.r * sin(this.a)
= this.r * sin(atan2(this.y, this.x) + rotation)
= this.r * (sin(atan2(this.y, this.x))cos(rotation) + cos(atan2(this.y, this.x))sin(rotation))
= this.r * ((this.y / this.r)cos(rotation) + (this.x / this.r)sin(rotation))
= this.y * cos(rotation) + this.x * sin(rotation)
```

Our new code looks like this:

```
x = this.x + this.speed
y = this.amp * Math.sin( x * this.cycles ) + this.center

this.x = x * cos(rotation_angle) - y * sin(rotation_angle);
this.y = y * cos(rotation_angle) + x * sin(rotation_angle);
```

We introduced variables `x` and `y` since we need each in its original form to calculate each of `this.x` and `this.y`. We no longer need to work in polar coordinates because our identities allowed us to eliminate those intermediate steps. Also, if `rotation_angle` is constant, it can be pre-computed; otherwise, you can leave the calls in the calculation of each point and get spiral-type effects.

If you prefer not to work with angles at all, you can work in terms of arbitrary functions by using parametric definitions `x = f(t)` and `y = g(t)` to define a curve, determining the perpendicular at each point `t` - either by analytically finding and encoding `f'(t)` and `g'(t)` - or by approximating these numerically around points of interest. Then, you simply plot a point at a displacement along that directed normal line equal to the value you are currently calculating for `this.y`. So, if you wanted to plot a sine curve along a parabola, you could do this:

```
t += speed;
r = this.amp * Math.sin(t * this.cycles) + this.center;

x = t;
y = t * t;

dxdt = 1;
dydt = 2t;
dydx = dydt / dxdt;
if (-epsilon <= dydt && dydt <= epsilon) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y + r;
} else {
    normal = -1.0 / dydx;
    this.x = x + r * ( 1.0 / Math.sqrt(1 + dydx * dydx));
    this.y = y + r * (dydx / Math.sqrt(1 + dydx * dydx));
}
```

I haven't tried running that, so it might have some errors, but in theory those errors should be fixable so that you get the intended effect: a sine curve wrapped around the (directed!) parabola `y = x^2` oriented to from negative to positive `x`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed explanations. I'll test the different methods and write back about the results! But for the rotation you used, is it in radian, 360 degrees, or otherwise?

Comment: @KelvinZhao I think JavaScript is going to work in radians. You can always try it with the numeric angle ~1.5 and see whether the result looks more like a regular sine curve (this would happen if degrees are being used) or like a vertical sine curve (if radians are being used).

Comment: Seems like all the formulas didn't work. Heh. The coordinates jumped way off the screen and by large amounts.

Comment: @KelvinZhao Which ones didn't work? The first bit with this.a and this.r, the second stab with x cos - y sin and x sin + y cos, or the third bit for a sine curve wrapped around a parabola? I wouldn't be surprised if I made a big mistake in the last of these, but the first one is probably right (modulo some bugs) and the second one seems like it should be OK (in particular, for the second one, the distance from the origin is not changed (try squaring this.x and this.y and taking the square root; should be the same as the square root of x^2 + y^2 in the same sample... so it should be on screen.

Comment: @KelvinZhao I think I know what your problem is. The code is working fine, but it is rotating about the origin. This could cause your curve to be rotated off screen. To correct this, you will need to translate the points as well, by an amount determined by your intended center of rotation. So, if you want to rotate about (x, y) = (a, b), you can use the above code but you must then translate all points by (a, b) - (a', b') where (a', b') is the image of (a, b) after rotation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent two days trying to figure it out. @Patrick87